# QFileDialog: using getOpenFileName allow for non-existent files

Tags: c++, qt

I want to program a browse button with qt that opens a standard find file dialog. If the user enters a new file name in the dialog I want to create the file. If the file exists I want to open it.

I have a function that given a string will make that decision. However, `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` shows the user a error if the file doesn't exist, and `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName` asks the user for a confirmation to overwrite the file if it does exist (which I wouldn't do anyways, so it should not be showed).

Is there a qt standard implemented that could meet my need without having to create a custom class iheriting from `QFileDialog` or resorting to another similarly hairy situation?

Here is my current working code, with undesired behavior...

```
void Login::browseFile() {
    QString file = ui->txtFile->text();
    if (file.isEmpty()) { file = QDir::homePath(); }
    file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
        tr("Select Monage Database"), file,
        tr("Database Files (*.db)"));

    if (!file.isEmpty()) { OpenDb(file); }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google failed me, but a few more minutes scrutinizing the docs, and I found [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum):

> QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite 0x00000004  Don't ask for confirmation if an existing file is selected. By default confirmation is requested.

I was able to use this for `getSaveFileName` to achieve the functionality I desired. I had to specify the option `selectedFilter`, but just passed the default `0`.

Modified code:

```
void Login::browseFile() {
    QString file = ui->txtFile->text();
    if (file.isEmpty()) { file = QDir::homePath(); }
    file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
        tr("Select Monage Database"), file,
        tr("Database Files (*.db)"), 0,
        QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite);

    if (!file.isEmpty()) { OpenDb(file); }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, nowadays the function `getOpenFileName` has also the possibility of `QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite` and does work as well (bit a strange name but it works ...)